# Does blocking in beach volleyball need to be harder than in indoor?

Tags: volleyball, beach-volleyball

Question is about the rules of blocking the ball in beach volleyball and its differences from indoor.

Is there any other block differences from indoor volleyball other than counting as one of three possible touches?

Comment: "The argument is that block is supposed to be "hard" contact as in indoor it can be softer, but I think that "hard/soft" thing is important for passes sets and hits, but block can be as "soft" as in indoor." I honestly don't understand what you're asking here, but in any case in seems to be a separate question from the first half which is specifically about the rules. We have a strict "one question per post" rule on Stack Exchange, so it would probably be best to ask this as a new question after clearing up the language.

Comment: Folks voting "opinion based": I think the first question (2nd para) is entirely answerable here.

Comment: I've removed the unclear second half of this question and voted to reopen.

Comment: I got in argument with other players and referee that called blocking fault on me, because I dropped the ball using my fingers when playing indoor 4x4 (beach rules), but when I do same thing in 6x6 everything is fine. So I need to make sure if I am wrong or them, that I can use fingers and quick contact to drop the ball to empty court space when Im blocking bad oponent set that got to my side of court above the net and its the same for beach/indoor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any more differences from indoor volleyball other than that its counted as one of three possible touches?

No. Other than the unavoidable differences due to the number of players (and the existence of the libero in indoor volleyball), Rule 14 "Block" is identical between the [indoor](http://www.fivb.org/EN/Refereeing-Rules/documents/FIVB-Volleyball_Rules_2017-2020-EN-v06.pdf) and [beach](http://www.fivb.org/EN/Refereeing-Rules/Documents/FIVB-BeachVolleyball_Rules_2017-2020-EN-v05.pdf) apart from 14.4.1:

(Indoor)

> 14.4.1 A block contact **is not** counted as a team hit. Consequently, after  a block contact, a team is entitled to **three** hits to return the ball.

(Beach)

> 14.4.1 A blocking contact **is** counted as a team hit. The blocking team will have **only two** more hits after a blocking contact.

(my emphasis in both cases).